# Creating a session with specific session ID

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, httpsession

thank you you guys for looking at my post.

Due to grey areas in licensing issues, I have two instances of tomcat running. I'm using Apache proxy to seamlessly communicate between the two.

App1 lives in tomcatA.
App2 lives in tomcatB.

Both requires user authentication and uses sessions for storing data. App1 is the only one visible to outside world and all the requests that comes in to App2 are generated by JavaScripts from App1. Unfortunately, App1 has a session and sends that specific JSESSIONID to all the requests from App2. Since there isn't a session with that specific id in App2, it returns with errors.

Is there a way for me to initialize a session with specific id?
Is there a way for me to modify all the requests so that it puts the valid session id into the headers.

**Edit:** I need App2 to realize that requests coming through, from App1, with a particular session id maps to a session that App2 created.

Answer (score 2):

Even if both application lived in the same Tomcat, sessions would be different as they are issued on a per-app basis. Personally, I am not entirely convinced by this design.

If your question is how to propagate authentication to another app, use a single sign-on application like [Josso](http://www.josso.org/confluence/display/JOSSO1/JOSSO+-+Java+Open+Single+Sign-On+Project+Home) or a CAS; to share session data, you can use a centralized cache accessible from both applications and accessible through JSON.

And yes, session data is bad.

**Update:** can't you simply implement a handshake protocol like: app2/register/{app1 session id} - at this point you both hold both session ID's and you can correlate each other. This can be done also with a session listener.

Comment: I don't like the design either, but as co-op intern and leaving soon, I don't much choice and time to completely redesign. I do not need to share data between two sessions and I do not need to have authenticate the same way either. I edited the question to clarify.

Comment: SESSION Data is used so I do not have to query the database each time it needs certain information. It's small enough that It wasn't necessary for me to implement a structure that persists data.

Comment: With your edit I now better understand what you want to accomplish. You want to correlate App1 session with App2 session. I edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Is there a way to get the session other than from the HttpRequest. If there isn't the above solution won't work because it'll return null since there isn't a session in local tomcat with that session id. And since all the requests come from the client's javascript code and apache just routes it to different tomcat based on the URL pattern, it won't matter if App1 knows about the session Id of App2.

Comment: " I do not need to share data between two sessions and I do not need to have authenticate the same way either" - so why the heck do you need to access the other app/tomcat session? If you need to share some session data you definitely need a shared cache.

Comment: To have some data persist between requests for a "session". See we are trying to implement a analytic website, and out DB is pretty busy returning data. I needed a way to keep some data in memory to limit the number of DB query.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a different session cookie name (or path, if possible) for your tomcatB. tomcatB would thus consider the JSESSIONID cookie as any other cookie, and not as a session cookie.

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html.